# php simplexml-load-file parsed php

Tags: php, xml

I use this in my script:

```
$xml = file_get_contents('gapi.account.php');
print_r($xml);
```

Easy, right?

But now... the gapi.account.php isn't parsed, how to do this? The output of the parsed file is xml.

Thanks!

Comment: What's in `gapi.account.php`? Is it valid xml? What error/warning do you get?

Comment: use `var_dump($xml);` instead of `print_r($xml);`. What's the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the file from outside, let it run:

```
$xml = file_get_contents('http://www.example.org/gapi.account.php');
print_r($xml);
```

Answer (score 1):

`file_get_contents`does not execute anything you fetch. Server actually does that, so you'll have to call as a file on server like `file_get_contents('http://mydomain.com/gapi.account.php');`

Comment: Ahh, thanks. Would it safety wise be smart to use a URL that only the hostfile of the server knows? For example: file_get_contents('http://[[only my server hostfile knows this and is not external accessible]]/gapi.account.php');

Comment: There shouldn't be a problem using something like `file_get_contents(http://my.private.intranet/gapi.account.php');` so you should be fine. [I hope I understood correctly what were you asking :)]